# Detect if Azure SQL Data Warehouse has running or queued operations

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-rest-api

I'm using the [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-manage-compute-rest-api) inside a Logic App. Every evening, the logic app checks the DW to see if the status is "Online", and if TRUE it issues a Pause. This is working, but does not take into account whether the DW has any operations active or queued. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-manage-compute-overview), issuing a pause "cancels all running or queued operations".

I don't want to lose or impact anyone's work, so I would like to pause only if the DW is idle. Is there a way to detect whether there are any running or queued operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - use a query based on the 'Monitor active queries' example at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-manage-monitor#step-1-identify-the-query-you-wish-to-investigate).

Something like:

```
select    count(*)
from      sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests
where     status not in ('Completed','Failed','Cancelled')
          and session_id <> session_id()
```

The session_id clause makes sure that you're not counting your own query.